# Matlab Parfor loop not working

Tags: matlab, parfor

I'm fitting a models to several datasets with `fminsearch`, and I'm trying to do them in parallel. My code is running up to the start of the `parfor` loop, but **the parfor loop seems to take forever** to start! (The first line in the parfor is not executed). There are no errors, matlab just remains "busy".

I'm running on local cluster with 4 cores, started with `matlabpool 4`, which appears to start up fine. I'm running Matlab R2014b 64bit on Ubuntu 14.04.3, eight core i7-3770K @ 3.50GHz, 24GiB RAM (most is unused of course).

### EDIT

Here is code that reproduces the problem!

file `matlab_parfor_test_2`

```
function f=matlab_parfor_test_2
f={}; 
for i=1:400
  a=@(p)i*p;             % make some functions depending on i
  b=@(p)a(p)+0;          % a function depending on this
  f=[f { @(p)b(p) }];    % create a list of i functions using this
end
```

file `matlab_parfor_test_1`

```
function matlab_parfor_test_1
f=matlab_parfor_test_2(); % create the functions
f=f(1:2);       % discard all but two functions
for i=1:2       % for each function                ('A')
  parfor j=1    % dummy parfor 
    tmp=f{i}; % just read a function from the cell ('B')
  end
end
```

The time taken to get from 'A' to the first 'B' (ie. time taken to "enter" the `parfor`) on my machine is

```
returning 400 functions: 20 sec
          500 functions: 32 sec
          600 functions: 45 sec
          700 functions: 64 sec
```

This is very odd, because in `test_1` I discard all but 2 of those functions! Why should the discarded functions cause slowing?

I thought perhaps matlab is not actually deleting the unwanted functions in `f`. So I tried replacing `f=f(1:2)` with

```
f={f{1}, f{2}};
```

but this also did not help.

If I replace the `parfor` with `for`, then of course it takes under 1ms to execute.

Any ideas??

### OLD VERSION OF QUESTION

```
function fit_all
  models = createModelFunctions();  % creates cell of function handles
  data   = { [1 2 3], [1 2 3] };    % create 2 data sets
  for i = 1:length(models)
    fprintf('model %g\n',i);
    parfor j = 1:length(data)
      fprintf('data %g\n',j);
      tmp = models{i};  % if I comment this line out, it runs fine!
      % p(j) = fminsearch(@(p)models{j}(p,data{j}), [0 0]);
    end
  end
```

the model functions are created in another file,

```
function models = createModelFunctions()
  models{1} = @(p,d) likelihoodfun(0,0,p,d);
  models{2} = @(p,d) likelihoodfun(1,0,p,d); 

function L = likelihoodfun(a,b,p,d)
  L = some maths here;
```

Running `fit_all`, I expected to see a list of `model 1`, `data 1`, `data 2`, `model 2` etc.. The output I'm getting is

```
model 1
```

then the thing just stops: no prompt, matlab says "busy", UI and OS are responsive as usual. System monitor shows only 1 core is active. It never makes it into the `parfor`.
If I press `ctrl+C` at this point, after a 3-minute delay I get

```
Operation terminated by user during parallel.internal.pool.serialize (line 21)
In distcomp.remoteparfor (line 69)
                serializedInitData = parallel.internal.pool.serialize(varargin);
In parallel_function>iMakeRemoteParfor (line 1060)
P = distcomp.remoteparfor(pool, W, @make_channel, parfor_C);
In parallel_function (line 444)
        [P, W] = iMakeRemoteParfor(pool, W, parfor_C);
```

If I comment out the line indicated, it works -- so the problem seems to be when I access the model functions... Similarly, it works fine if I change models to

```
 models={@sum,@sum}
```

i.e. it's just when I'm using function handles from another file...

Comment: I am running Matlab 2014a 64 bit on Windows and I cannot reproduce your problem (it works fine). I would try 2 things: (1) put the parfor in the outer loop. (2) Try to implement it without cell arrays. (2) is more a shot in the dark, but I had problem in the past with struct array and parfor, so maybe...

Comment: Hmm you're right. It must be to do with the function itself. If I replace it with a very simple external function, there's no problem. I'll experiment.

Comment: I meant that I tried it with your function (just setting `L=0`) and it works fine.

Comment: I have run some new tests! The results are unexpected. Question edited. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code on my machine it runs fine. Both on my Windows and Linux. However, the first run always take a bit longer because you have to open up a parallel pool, is this what you're referring to? If so, this is normal and expected behavior.

FYI, you should be using parpool instead of matlabpool. Maybe the lagacy matlabpool code is having problems creating the pool? Also, make sure it's not closing your parallel pool each time.

If none of that works, try the code on someone else's computer and see if you can re-create the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've met the same situation before. Please note that when using parallel computation, normally we users are not able to see the real time operation of the program of each worker. That is to say, as long as your code is not finished, when you pause your script you will always see the pointer pointing to the first line of the parfor loop, which means parameter transfer and calculation are being performed.
Please reduce the number of loop cycles and you will probably see the expected results in a short time.